# python fork and pipe for sending and receiving messages

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, pipe, fork

My application need two (python) methods to send and receive messages(arrays). I am trying to achieve this by using a pipe. I have forked two processes. I observe that if (process == 0), I can either send or receive message from one end (Please correct me if I am wrong). I want both ends of the pipe to be able to send and receive messages to each other. I am new to pipe and fork in python (and to the concept in general) and hence I am finding difficulty in identifying problem with my code. Do i have to use two pipes in order to achieve my goal?

This is the code I am trying to implement:

```
start, end = os.pipe()

def communication():
    process1 = os.fork()

    if process1:
        r = os.fdopen(start, 'w')
        parent_writes = [1,2,3,4]
        data = json.dumps(parent_writes)
        r.write(data)
        print("Parent writes = ", data)
    else:
        childRead = os.fdopen(end)
        data = childRead.read()
        print("Child reads =", data)

    process2 = os.fork()
    if process2:
        os.close(start)
        w = os.fdopen(end, 'w')
        child_writes = [6, 7, 8, 9]
        data = json.dumps(child_writes)
        w.write(data)
        print("Child writes = ", data)
    else:
        os.close(end)
        parentRead = os.fdopen(start)
        arr = parentRead.read()
        print("Parent reads =", arr)

communication()
```

This is my output and error message:

```
Parent writes =  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Child writes =  [6, 7, 8, 9]
Parent reads = [6, 7, 8, 9]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/ssss/PycharmProjects/tttt/forkAndPipe.py", line 35, in 
<module>communication()
File "/Users/ssss/PycharmProjects/tttt/forkAndPipe.py", line 17, in 
communication
data = childRead.read()
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Unless I am mistaken, "Bad file descriptor" has got something to do with the way I am forking or closing ends of the pipe inappropriately.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have two unconditional forks, so you are starting 3 new processes for a total of 4. I'm not sure exactly what you wanted, but I'm guessing you only wanted 1 new process so that you have 2 in total, your main and the child? Regardless you'll generally want `sys.exit(0)` in every `else` branch here so that the child does its job and exits. If you want bidirectional communication, you'll indeed want two pipes (otherwise the child may write and then immediately read its own data which is silly)

Comment: Thank you for your input! Yes the idea is to send messages from one method to another and receive too! I am guessing with just 1 new process(2 in total), I will not be able to achieve this goal?